# How to reference another schema from an array schema in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi

I have an OpenAPI 3.0 schema where one of the properties (the `taskRequireSkills` array) needs to reference another schema (`TaskRequireUserSkill`), like this:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:

    Task:
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string

        taskRequireSkills:
          type: array
            schema:  # ERROR : bad indentation of a mapping entry
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/TaskRequireUserSkill'

        created_at:
          type: string
          format: datetime

    TaskRequireUserSkill:
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        skill_id:
          type: integer
        skill_name:
          type: string
        ordering:
          type: integer
        created_at:
          type: string
          format: datetime
```

But I get the "bad indentation of a mapping entry" error.
I suppose my syntax is invalid.
But which syntax is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array of $refs is defined as follows:

```yaml
        taskRequireSkills:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/TaskRequireUserSkill'
```